# Can I tell rsnapshot to tar every file?

Tags: linux, backup

Is it possible to backup a set of files with rsync, but not as regular files but archived with tar (each file)?

My problem is: I need/want to make backups of my home-folder at work and IT gave me access to a NAS through some personal cifs-shares. I always used rsnapshot for stuff like this but with this nice cifs-share this won't work well, because it neither can store permissions properly nor handle symlinks at all or stuff like this. So my idea was: tar every file before putting it on the share and let it handle the tricky stuff (this works great for stage4-files or stuff like that).

Is this possible or if not: do you know any other tool which can handle this scenario?